# jqGrid DatePicker isn't being Initialised in Complex Search Dialog

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jqGrid with "multipleSearch=true" and "multipleGroup=true" to allow complex searches.

I have the "stype" set for the columns, (in my case this includes "date", "text", "integer" and "currency").

I have also provided "dataInit" functions for the DatePicker and AutoComplete plugins for the "date" and "text" columns respectively.

When I open the Search Dialog, the AutoComplete "dataInit" function is called but not the DatePicker "dataInit" function.

This appears to be because the "dataInit" function is triggered when a new filter is created and is based upon the "stype" of the first column.

(It should I suspect be triggered when the user selects a column from the dropdown list in the Search Dialog.)

Is there a way to display the DatePicker when a user wants to search a "date" field and disable it for other field "stypes"?

I've included the relevant code snippets below:

```
var DatePickerCfg = { id: 'DatePicker',dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',minDate: new Date(1990,0,1),maxDate: new Date(2099,12,31),showOn: 'focus' };
var AutoCompleteCfg = { id: 'AutoComplete',source: '' };



var formatoptions = {};
var searchoptions = {};


else if (Field['Type'] == '[datetime]')
{
 stype = 'date';
 formatoptions = {srcformat: 'Y-m-dTH:i:s', newformat: 'd/m/Y g:i:s A'};
 searchoptions = {sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge'], dataInit: function(el) {setTimeout(function() {jQuery(el).datepicker(DatePickerCfg);}, 200);}};
}
else {searchoptions = {sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','ew','en','cn','nc'], dataInit:function(el) {setTimeout(function() {jQuery(el).autocomplete(AutoCompleteCfg);},200);}};}

colModel.push({name:Field['Field'], index:Field['Field'], align:Field['Align'], sortable:true, stype:stype, formatter:stype, formatoptions:formatoptions, searchoptions:searchoptions});
```

Comment: I have noticed in various C# and VB examples on the Trirand website that they have managed to get this working... no clues in their code of course since they are using their proprietary server-side libraries.

see link below:
http://www.trirand.net/a...id/searchdialogmultiple

In their "SetUpSearchDialogMultipleGrid" function they explicitly configure the search dialog to use the DataPicker, but its all in C# and VB.Net with no actual code detailing what they are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to use the Search Dialog but had a similar issue when using inline-editing. The problem is that DatePicker needs to know the DOM element its going to act upon. The dataInit fires to early. I'm sure that's why you are using the setTimeout function which the documentation states can be used as a alternative - oddly it doesn't work.

I solved this by doing the following:

```
colModel:[ {classes:'applyDatePicker',edittype:"checkbox"
```

When the row goes into editMode there is a callback function

```
function onEditRow(rowId) { 
    var dp = jQuery('.applyDatePicker>input[type="text"]');
    jQuery(dp).each(function () {
        jQuery(this).bind('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).datepicker();
            jQuery(this).focus();
        });
    });
}
```

Maybe you can use a similar approach but instead apply it in the afterShowSearch callback function?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault... I had set the stype on my date column to "date" instead of "text". stype refers to the type of input in the search dialog and not the type of data. (I discovered this by trawling the source code)